# Excel Line & Scatter Graph - Plotting Scatter Points

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Firstly apologies if I miss anything or get anything wrong, I am more familiar with StackOverflow than SuperUser. So please don't hesitate to ask for more details or to improve my question.

I am trying to create a line and scatter graph in Microsoft Excel. Now I can plot the lines without any problem, using the A,B,C,D values as series and then the year column as the horizontal axis labels.

| Year | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1991 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 15 |
| 1992 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 14 |
| 1993 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 13 |
| 1994 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 12 |
| 1995 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 11 |
| 1996 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 10 |
| 1997 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 9 |
| 1998 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 8 |

The problem I have is trying to add the scatter points. I am expecting to see 3 scatter points at values of 12, 13 & 14 in the 1995 section, however only the first point appears as a dot in the graph. I am adding the value as a new series to get this behaviour, not sure if this is correct?

Now I can overcome this if I create individual series for each of the three items but I'm not sure if this best way?

Any advice is greatly appreciated and thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Thanks for the comments, here is some extra detail.

So columns A, B, C & D should form a traditional line, and then yes, there is another table which should simply form points.

| Year | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1995 | 12 |
| 1995 | 13 |
| 1995 | 14 |
| 1998 | 11 |

So the resulting graph looks something like this:

[image]

I have created these using manual series input like below, is this correct?

[image]

Comment: `1995` shows values `7` (A), `8` (B), `9` (C), `11` (D) in your example; why would you expect `12, 13 & 14` there? Is a table missing maybe?

Comment: @P.b Have just added further details

Comment: Again, your example is different from your data. Your data doesn't show year 1999 nor does it show value 12.16, but the chart shows them correctly given these values (that do not resemble your table values).

Comment: Try rearranging your data like shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekiFN.png and use Scatter with Straight Lines and Markers?

Comment: @P.b Yes data is different as tried to simplify it for the purpose of the question. Thank you that screenshot is very helpful for rearranging the data, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to achieve. In a scatter plot each x-value represents a value, whereas in a linear plot each x-value is an indepedent label. So which variant do you need?
[image: Two plots]

Comment: Have just added further details to the original question